# Dishwasher gurgling

Tags: plumbing, dishwasher

I'm new to plumbing and trying to understand if I can fix a very loud gurgling that occurs during operation of our quiet dishwasher.  I have seen other answers on this forum and elsewhere, but I don't think they cover my set up.

I hear the sound coming out of the air gap next to the faucet.  I can't get a good picture of the plumbing, but am including my best freehand drawing below.  The air gap seems to be installed correctly, according to my read of [Wikipedia's Air gap Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_gap_(plumbing)#Function) section.

Would be appreciative of any advice to a newbie on whether the plumbing looks OK and/or where to look for the source of the issue.

[image]

Comment: `gurgling` is usually the sound of blockage somewhere

Comment: Looks like you need an AAV somewhere.  I don't really understand the double drainpipe.

Comment: If it's connected to the disposal, that connection usually provides enough air admittance. I think I'd sbeed to see/hear the actual setup to have any opinion. Ad yes, the drain as sketched is _weird_ and might be the problem.

Comment: Thanks.  The drain seemed odd to me, as well -- I haven't gone under the house to check, but could the right side go to a vent?  It is an island sink/dishwasher.